# Does order matter when verifying an X.509 store in OpenSSL (Python)?

Tags: python, openssl, pyopenssl

I noticed that changing the order of the two intermediate CAs (when one is irrelevant) results in a different verification result:

```py
root_1, chain_1, leaf_1 = generate_chain()  # root, intermediate, leaf
root_2, chain_2, leaf_2 = generate_chain()

r0 = validate_chain(leaf_1, [chain_1], root_1)    # leaf, intermediates, root
r1 = validate_chain(leaf_1, [chain_1, chain_2], root_1)
r2 = validate_chain(leaf_1, [chain_2, chain_1], root_1)

print(r0, r1, r2) # True True False
```

I was under the impression that the order that certs are added to an X.509 store did not matter. I also didn't seem to find anything in the [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/X509_verify_cert.html) about this. Can anyone clarify?

Example (source): https://gist.github.com/kaedenbrinkman/c5f2b7d05034999cd55821a4f3403720

Comment: The chain should not contain extraneous certificates. No doubt the result if they do is undefined. Solution: don't.

Comment: Is this officially documented anywhere? My understanding is that a store is like a "pool" of certs and verify() checks if a valid chain exists in that pool, so extraneous certs should not affect the result.